# Left join on character + linking value

Tags: mysql

I'll keep this simple. I need to left join 2 tables, Master & Child both with a PartNum field. Values for the fields are like this:

```
Master
-----
1003
1004
1005
...

Child
-----
1003
C1003
K1003
pp1003
cc1003
1004
...
```

I only want to join on child records beginning with a single 'C',

so...

1003 would only return C1003

Any help for this MySql newbie would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from master m
left join child c on concat('C', m.PartNum) = c.PartNum
```

Comment: Thank you both! Juergen, your solution is too simple! What you call a blind spot. P.S. My middle name is Jurgen!

Comment: It should work. See [this SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56dea/5). Doesn't it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT c.prod
FROM master m 
LEFT JOIN child c ON c.prod = CONCAT('C', CAST(m.prod AS CHAR))
```